# How to count the Search content which coming from db

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I found the description of the search term and got that using JQuery autocomplete. now i want to show the count of the search term(word) for each description.

```cs
<strike>
if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) )
        {
            //searching description and name in TrainingTopic
            var modeltrainingtopic = db.TrainingTopicRepository.Get( ).Where(x => x.Description.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( )) || x.Name.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( ))).Select(x => new SearchViewModel { Id = x.Id, IsTrainingTopic=true, Description = x.Description, Name = x.Name, RedirectionLink = "" }).Take(10).ToList( );

            //searching description, content and name in SubTopic
            var modelsubtopic = db.SubTopicRepository.Get( ).Where(x => x.Description.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( )) || x.Name.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( )) || x.SubTopicContent.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( ))).Select(x => new SearchViewModel { Id = x.Id,IsSubTopic=true, Description = x.Description, Content = x.SubTopicContent, RedirectionLink = "" }).Take(10).ToList( );

            //searching description, content and name in SubSubTopic
            var modelsubsubtopic = db.SubSubTopicRepository.Get( ).Where(x => x.Description.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( )) || x.Name.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( )) || x.Content.ToLower( ).Contains(searchTerm.ToLower( ))).Select(x => new SearchViewModel { Id = x.Id,IsSubSubTopic=true, Name = x.Name, Description = x.Description, Content = x.Content, RedirectionLink = "" }).Take(10).ToList( );
            return modeltrainingtopic.Concat(modelsubtopic).Concat(modelsubsubtopic);
        }
</strike>
```

in my view model, i have added StringCount. now i want to add the count of the search term in each object(modeltrainingtopic,modelsubtopic,modelsubsubtopic). the below how i add jquery

```js
$(function () {

    var loc = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    $("#srch-term").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/" + loc + "/api/ResourceLanding/SearchString?searchTerm=" + request.term,
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.length) {
                        var result = [
                         {
                             id: 0,
                             label: 'No matches found'
                         }
                        ];
                        response(result);
                    }
                    else {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Description, value: item.Description, Id:item.Id, IsTrainingTopic: item.IsTrainingTopic, IsSubTopic: item.IsSubTopic, IsSubSubTopic: item.IsSubSubTopic, Name: item.Name, Content: item.Content };
                        }))
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var icon;
        if (item.IsTrainingTopic) {
            icon = '<i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
        }
        else if (item.IsSubTopic) {
            icon = '<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
        }
        else if (item.IsSubTopic) {
            icon = '<i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
        }
        if (icon !== undefined) {
            return $("<li>")
              .append("<div style='width:100%' data-id=" + item.value + ">" + icon + "  " + item.label + "</div>")
              .appendTo(ul);
        }
        else {
            return $("<li>")
            .append("<div style='width:100%' data-id=" + item.value + ">" + item.label + "</div>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        }
    };
});
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lengthy but also one other way :

1.)

Just create a class with properties which you will get in you main list "modeltrainingtopic " from table as follow:

```
    public class YourListItems
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsTrainingTopic { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string RedirectionLink { get; set; }
        public int SearchCount { get; set; }

    }
```

2.)
Create method that will return "SearchTerm" word count like:

```
 static int CountWords(string StringInWhichYouNeedToSearch,string SearchTerm)
 {
       return Regex.Matches(StringInWhichYouNeedToSearch, SearchTerm).Count;
 }
```

3.)

Now create list object of class "YourListItems" type.

```
        List<YourListItems> myFinalList = new List<YourListItems>();
```

4.)

Now iterate loop for each row of list which you are getting from table "modeltrainingtopic"

```
        foreach (var SingleRow in modeltrainingtopic)
        {

//It will count search term in your description , name and content

 int SearchCount = CountWords(SingleRow.Description, searchTerm) + CountWords(SingleRow.Name, searchTerm) + CountWords(SingleRow.Content, searchTerm);



//Will add row to new list object named myFinalList 
            myFinalList.Add(

              new YourListItems
              {
                  Id = SingleRow.Id,
                  IsTrainingTopic = SingleRow.IsTrainingTopic,
                  Description = SingleRow.Description,
                  Content = SingleRow.Content,
                  Name = SingleRow.Name,
                  RedirectionLink = SingleRow.RedirectionLink,
                  SearchCount = SearchCount,

              }

            );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i haveto store the search word count in each object created. i want to know how to write the code. please help me if you have any idea

Comment: I have edited my answer.Please check.Hope it will help you.

Comment: those method we stored as a list bro.. in the list how can we directly find the search term in description?

Comment: Means...Bro  you need count of your "searchTerm" from :     "modeltrainingtopic.Description"?

Comment: Bro, see the backend code. there i took data from 3 table. in that i have took searchterm data from descrption, name and content. i append the data row separately.  So i want the count, how many search term is there in one row. for example, in method modeltrainingtopic list, i want the count of search term in 1st each row in that method

Comment: Pranav_Systematix, found way for that bro. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great..Thanks you too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my question.

```
var topicData= db.TrainingTopicRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()) || x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).Select(x=>x).Take(10).ToList();
var modeltrainingtopic = topicData.Select(x => new SearchViewModel { Id = x.Id,StringCount= topicData.Where(s =>s.Id==x.Id&& s.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).Count()+ topicData.Where(s => s.Id == x.Id && s.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).Count(), IsTrainingTopic = true, Description = x.Description, Name = x.Name, RedirectionLink = "" }).ToList();
```

Here i took the old list and compare my id then count the searchterm in each list